# Does Azure App Service for Linux support http2?

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, http2, azure-web-app-service

SSL configuration is handled upstream on Azure App Service.

So running an App Service as Docker container and configuring Nginx for server { listen 443 ssl h2; } is not necessary and in fact, will not render a webpage.

How do I modify the configuration on Azure App Service for Linux to run as http2 protocol when SSL w/ customer domain is setup on the service?

Thanks,

Comment: Very good question here and, I believe, wrong answers.

http/2 generally assumes https (which is debatable but seems a fact).
However, as per tradition, azure's https and http/2 only work at the front server and not further (the question could make that more clear). I've been trying to move to a http/2 (no https) nginx on our docker instance and a black-out followed. The client cannot.

Note: http/2 really is worth only if you make it till the end: managing the sockets and juggling between availability needs to see app-servers' resources. 

Can I suggest a question change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature now exists for both Linux and Windows and is in the same section of the Azure Portal for Web App Services.

1. Go to your Web App Service
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Configuration
4. Select the tab for General Settings
5. Beneath Platform Settings, choose the "2.0" from the Http version drop down.
6. See image for details.

[image]

Comment: As of June 16, 2017 the following statement has been added to that link, by Microsoft: "_...work has officially started to enable HTTP/2 for App Service. We will share a more concrete timeline as it becomes available_"

Comment: However, the performance benefits of http/2 are only true if you can dive till the app-server and the static resources: only with this information can you chunk the delivery effectively which is where http/2 makes a real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, I don't think you need to do any special settings to support HTTP2 on Azure WebApps for Linux. Azure WebApps for Linux is a Docker container instance, and HTTP2 protocol is implemented noramlly as a library for programming language or directly supported by HTTP server. According to the [implementations](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) listed at http2 offical site, you just need to install the Nginx version `1.9.5+` which can support HTTP2 protocol. If you want to use, only enable it. Please refer to the [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-9-5/) from nginx offical site.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nginx must be configured, in nginx.conf.  I'm simply asking if this is being used by default when SSL is used.  Azure App Service doesn't require configuring SSL it's handed upstream.  Which is why i'm not obvious if they are using it or not.

Comment: Also, i can see on chrome that's it's serving up without H2

Comment: @A.Wentzel: it is not active by default on the front proxy of Azure. You can activate it (and it works) but it will not be the best experience.